# How to represent the following in sum notation,also notify if this is any special series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$\color{blue}{1.}~~ -x+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}\cdots \infty$

and

$\color{blue}{2.}~~ \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^6}{6}-\frac{x^8}{8}\cdots \infty$

i know $1,3,5,7\cdots$ can be represented using the $n^{th}$ term $2n-1 ,~~n\in \mathbb{N}$.

And $2,4,6,8\cdots$ can be represented using the $n^{th}$ term $2n,~~n\in \mathbb{N}$.

But i am worried about the alternating $+$ and $-$ signs.

also notify if this is any special series etc.

Comment: Hint: use $(-1)^n$ (or $(-1)^{n+1}$) to get an alternating sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i am worried about the alternating + and − signs.

Alternating minus sign can can be represented by $(-1)^n$

> also notify if this is any special series etc.

**Hint 1:**
$$\arctan x=x-x^3/3+x^5/5+x^7/7-...\\$$
**Spoiler: Answer**

> $$-\arctan x$$

**Hint 2:**
$$\ln(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3+x^4/4-x^5/5+...\tag{$|x|<1$}$$
**Spoiler: Answer**

> $$\frac12[\ln(1+ix)+\ln(1-ix)]=\frac12\ln(1+x^2)=\ln\sqrt{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$

---

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{x^{2n}}{2n}$$